# how to get values from 2 tables based on common table

Tags: mysql, join

//Table 1 (favourite)

```
id || user_id || event_id || news_id
1        1          1           0
2        1          0           1
```

//Table 2 (event)

```
event_id || name || location || descr
   1        jit       ekm       demo
```

//Table 3 (news)

```
 news_id || title || news || location
    1       Demo      no       thr
```

My question is from `Table 1`, when `news_id` field is `0` then display values from `Table 2` according to `event_id` values in `Table 1` and when `event_id` field is `0` then display values from `Table 3` according to `news_id` values in `Table 1`.

Is this possible. How to make this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should probably do the trick for you-- it's joining the tables based on the values present in the `favourite` table:

```sql
SELECT    f.id, f.user_id,
          e.event_id, e.name event_name, e.location event_location, e.descr event_descr,
          n.news_id, n.title news_title, n.news, n.location news_location
FROM      favourite f
LEFT JOIN event e ON e.event_id = f.event_id
LEFT JOIN news  n ON n.news_id  = f.news_id
```